# Umbraco 8 Examine/Lucene query returns no results in code but searching from the backoffice works as expected

Tags: lucene.net, umbraco8, examine

I'm trying to do a simple Lucene query in a fresh Umbraco 8 site (8.13.0, Examine 1.1, Lucene.Net 3.0.3).

I'm trying to get all documents of a specific type but I get no results back.

```
ExamineManager.Instance.TryGetIndex(Constants.UmbracoIndexes.ExternalIndexName, out var index);
var searcher = index.GetSearcher();
var query = searcher.CreateQuery()
                    .NodeTypeAlias(BlogPost.ModelTypeAlias);
var result = query.Execute();

var rawQuery = query.ToString(); // == "{ Category: , LuceneQuery: +__NodeTypeAlias:blogpost }"

// result.Results.Count == 0
// result.TotalItemCount == 3
// result.TopDocs.TotalHits == 3
```

If I take the raw Lucene query `+__NodeTypeAlias:blogpost` and stick it in the search field in Examine Management in Umbraco I get 3 results as expected:

[image]

Why isn't it working from code? (What am I doing wrong?)

Comment: "Category:" ~ could it be this? That searching on an empty/null value is causing an issue?

Comment: Nope, I've the same issue. And while I agree it's probably a good idea to limit the scope which for normal applications would be "content" (or better use IndexTypes.Content to get this value) it's not a solution to the given issue

I have the same and all documentation I can find if prior to Umbraco 8.10 (using Umbraco 8.17.1) so either it's broke or has changed I think

Note that doing a native query doesn't either:

 var test3 = searcher.CreateQuery(IndexTypes.Content).NativeQuery("+nodeName:qwerty keywords:qwerty");
var test4 = test3.Execute(); // zero results -> in backend 3 results